# Ajax Php Dynamic autofill not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I am pretty new to ajax. Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source:'getautocomplete.php',
            minLength:1
    });
});
```

And this is the relevant portion from getautocomplete.php

```
$term=$_GET["name"];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock where itemid like '%".$term."%' order by itemid ");
$json=array();

while($st=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[]=array(
        'value'=> $st["itemid"],
        'label'=>$st["itemid"]."  "
    );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

and my HTML form looks like this

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="auto"     >
```

What it does is load all elements of the table and list it up, but I want only the result that matches with the input text. what changes have to be made

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
        {$.ajax({url: 'getautocomplete.php',
            data:{name: 'passed_name', minLength: 1},
            success: function(data){
                 $("#name2").html(data);
            }
         }
```

You did not pass your name for $_GET["name"]; in your code.